# Luma Icons - add font-display:swap

Tags: magento2.3, fonts

How can I add font-display:swap to following Luma icon fonts

```
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'luma-icons';
  src: url('../fonts/Luma-Icons.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/Luma-Icons.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

It is loading from en_US/css/styles-m.css but I am not able to find this code in Magento lib or vendor default Magento2 themes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to edit the mixin that is used to create that CSS:

If you look in `lib/web/css/source/lib/_typography.less` you'll find:

```
.lib-font-face(
    @family-name,
    @font-path,
    @font-format: false,
    @font-weight: normal,
    @font-style: normal,
    @font-display: auto
) when not (@font-format = false) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: @family-name;
        src: url('@{font-path}.@{font-format}') format(@font-format);
        font-weight: @font-weight;
        font-style: @font-style;
        font-display: @font-display;
    }
}
```

Overwrite that file in your theme or create a new mixin/function to overwrite this one and include your CSS in there but please note this will apply to all uses of `.lib-font-face`.

You don't need to edit this but for the sake of understanding how this works:

1. Font path variable (`@icons__font-path`) is declared in `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/web/css/source/_theme.less`
2. This is used in `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_icons.less` to add the fonts, and because the variable was overridden above it pulls in the Luma fonts using the `.lib-font-face` mixin/function I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks , I will try this out and let you know the outcome , When you say it will apply to all uses of .lib-font-face , do you see any potential issue that can break the frontend ?

Comment: Not really, it's unlikely that will cause issues and even if it does it's hardly used on the frontend.

Comment: Thanks Ben , Its working fine

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: @Pravin how did you override that mixin?